# Separate Clearly Defined clusters with DBSCAN

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dbscan

I have a dataset with 4 features,with features (1,4) and (2,4) clearly separable.
[image]

I am trying to use **DBSCAN** to come up with the Clusters, however I am unable to create satisfatocty clusters.

Here is the code snippet where I:

- iterate over all combinations of eps and min_sample values.
- Run DBSCAN
- save the results if Clustes are more than 1, and less than 7

```py
#### STEP 4: DBSCAN ####
# Define the parameter combinations to evaluate
eps_values = [0.01, 0.03, 0.05, 0.07, 0.1, 0.15]
min_samples_values = [2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 15]

# Iterate over parameter combinations
names = []
for eps, min_samples in itertools.product(eps_values, min_samples_values):
    # Create a DBSCAN object with the current parameter values
    dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=min_samples)

    # Fit the DBSCAN model to the data and obtain the cluster labels
    cluster_labels = dbscan.fit_predict(df_t[new_features])
    if len(pd.Series(cluster_labels).unique()) > 1: 
        if len(pd.Series(cluster_labels).unique()) < 7: 
            name = f"eps_{eps}_mins_{min_samples}"
            df_t[name] = cluster_labels
            names.append(name)
    # Filter out the outliers (-1 label) from the cluster labels
    filtered_labels = cluster_labels[cluster_labels != -1]
    print("Eps:", eps, "Min Samples:", min_samples, "clusters:", len(pd.Series(filtered_labels).unique()))
```

Here I am plotting the reuslts for clusters that have more than 1, less than 7 clusters. As you can see none of the param gave satisfactory clusters that look like the origianl data.
[image]

**Q:**  is it the code/setup that is making it unable to cluster properely?

Here is the complete code that reproduces the example, for completeness.
the steps are:

- import the data
- scale using minmax
- create new features using kernel PCA
- run DBSCAN
  the first 3 steps are just to setup the dataframe DATA to have hte correct features.

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
import zipfile
import seaborn as sns,  matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.manifold import MDS
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN


from itertools import combinations
import itertools 
%matplotlib inline

#### SETUP TO MAKE THE DATA ####


#### STEP1: IMPORT THE DATA ####

# Specify the URL of the ZIP file
zip_url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/static/public/267/banknote+authentication.zip'

# Download the ZIP file
response = requests.get(zip_url)

# Save the ZIP file locally
zip_path = 'banknote_authentication.zip'
with open(zip_path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)

# Extract the contents of the ZIP file
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall()

# Specify the path to the extracted CSV file
csv_path = 'data_banknote_authentication.txt'
column_names = ['variance', 'skewness', 'curtosis', 'entropy', 'original']
features  = ['variance', 'skewness', 'curtosis', 'entropy']
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, names=column_names)



##### STEP2: SCALE THE DATA ####
mms = MinMaxScaler()
data = df.copy()
for col in features:
    data[col] = mms.fit_transform(data[[col]]).squeeze()


### STEP 3: TRANFORM KERNEL PCA ####

embedding =  MDS(n_components=4,max_iter=300, random_state=10)

X_transformed = embedding.fit_transform(data[features])
new_features = ["1","2", "3", "4"]
df_t=pd.DataFrame(X_transformed , columns=new_features)
df_t['original'] = data["original"]



### SHOW THE DATA 
sns.set_context('notebook')
sns.set_style('white')
sns.pairplot(df_t, hue="original")


### CODE FOR MAKING DBSCAN AND PLOTS 

#### STEP 4: DBSCAN ####
# Define the parameter combinations to evaluate
eps_values = [0.01, 0.03, 0.05, 0.07, 0.1, 0.15]
min_samples_values = [2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 15]

# Iterate over parameter combinations
names = []
for eps, min_samples in itertools.product(eps_values, min_samples_values):
    # Create a DBSCAN object with the current parameter values
    dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=min_samples)

    # Fit the DBSCAN model to the data and obtain the cluster labels
    cluster_labels = dbscan.fit_predict(df_t[new_features])
    if len(pd.Series(cluster_labels).unique()) > 1: 
        if len(pd.Series(cluster_labels).unique()) < 7: 
            name = f"eps_{eps}_mins_{min_samples}"
            df_t[name] = cluster_labels
            names.append(name)


    # Filter out the outliers (-1 label) from the cluster labels
    filtered_labels = cluster_labels[cluster_labels != -1]
    print("Eps:", eps, "Min Samples:", min_samples, "clusters:", len(pd.Series(filtered_labels).unique()))





###### PLOT THE DBSCAN RESULS #### 
df_plot = df_t.melt(id_vars =new_features, value_vars =['original'] + names , var_name = "cluster")
df_plot['value']= df_plot['value'].astype(str)


# Create a 3 by 3 subplot grid
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=4, figsize=(12, 12))

# Flatten the axes for easy iteration
axes = axes.flatten()

# Iterate over each cluster and create scatter plots
for i, cluster in enumerate(df_plot['cluster'].unique()):
    print (i)
    ax = axes[i]  # Select the current subplot

    # Filter data for the current cluster
    subset = df_plot[df_plot['cluster'] == cluster]

    # Create scatter plot
    sns.scatterplot(data=subset, x="2", y="4", hue='value', legend='full', ax=ax)

    # Set subplot title
    ax.set_title(f"Cluster {cluster}", fontsize=12)

    # Set axis labels
    ax.set_xlabel("x")
    ax.set_ylabel("y")

    # Remove x and y ticks
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])

# Adjust spacing between subplots
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

### Answering Gijs Wobben question: what's the point in having MDS with the same number of components as before?

From a lecture i am following, i was hoping to use MDS with the same number of dimensions to separate better the classes, helping with the clustering alghorithms. Here you can see how in this example provided in the lecture, the data is reorganized in a more visually separable manner.
[image]

Comment: It looks like the orange points are always drawn on top of the blue points, so it's hard to see whether these clusters are really as clearly separated as they appear. And even then, I'm not sure it will be possible to cleanly separate them, because they do touch, and the point density in the area where they touch seems to be fairly high.

Comment: I think looking at 2Dimensions they are ovelapping, but there is 4 dimensions, so maybe when looking at all the features they are separated. Is there a solution you know of to improve the outcome, even with this overalp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not super clear what it is you hope to find but in general you want to select scaling, dimensionality reduction and clustering methods that create the best separation for your use case. For example, if you want to separate the data into clusters based on the target you could use Min-Max scaling (so no negative values exist anymore), apply TSNE to get the best separation for a given target variable, and run KMeans on the result with a fixed number of clusters:

```py
import zipfile
from pathlib import Path

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# Fix the random seed for reproducibility
SEED = 42
np.random.seed(SEED)

##### STEP 1: IMPORT THE DATA #####

data_path = Path(__file__).parent / "data_banknote_authentication.txt"
if not data_path.exists():
    print("Download the data")
    # Specify the URL of the ZIP file
    zip_url = (
        "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/static/public/267/banknote+authentication.zip"
    )

    # Download the ZIP file
    response = requests.get(zip_url)

    # Save the ZIP file locally
    zip_path = "banknote_authentication.zip"
    with open(zip_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(response.content)

    # Extract the contents of the ZIP file
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, "r") as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall()

print("Load the data")
column_names = ["variance", "skewness", "curtosis", "entropy", "original"]
features = ["variance", "skewness", "curtosis", "entropy"]
target = "original"
df = pd.read_csv(data_path, names=column_names)


##### STEP 2: SCALE THE DATA #####

# Min-max scaling
print("Scale the data (min-max)")
min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaled_min_max = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df[features])
features_min_max = [f"{feature}_scaled_min_max" for feature in features]
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        pd.DataFrame(
            scaled_min_max,
            columns=features_min_max,
        ),
    ],
    axis=1,
)

##### STEP 3: DIMENSIONALITY REDUCTION ####

# T-SNE (or any other method that yields good separation)
print("Perform dimensionality reduction (T-SNE)")
multi_dimensional_scaler = TSNE(
    n_components=2,  # How may clusters do you hope to find?
    random_state=SEED,
)
scaled_multi_dimensional = multi_dimensional_scaler.fit_transform(df[features])
features_multi_dimensional = [
    f"tsne_component_{i}" for i in range(scaled_multi_dimensional.shape[1])
]
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        pd.DataFrame(
            scaled_multi_dimensional,
            columns=features_multi_dimensional,
        ),
    ],
    axis=1,
)

# # Optional: Show the separation
# df.plot.scatter(
#     x=features_multi_dimensional[0],
#     y=features_multi_dimensional[1],
#     c=target,
#     colormap="viridis",
# )


##### STEP 4: CLUSTERING #####

# K-means (or any other clustering method)
clustering = KMeans(
    n_clusters=2,  # How may clusters do you hope to find?
    n_init="auto",
    random_state=SEED,
)
df["cluster"] = clustering.fit_predict(X=df[features_multi_dimensional], y=df[target])

# # Optional: Show clusters over the original data
# plot = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(
#     df[features],
#     c=df["cluster"],
#     figsize=(10, 10),
#     marker="o",
#     hist_kwds={"bins": 20},
#     s=60,
#     alpha=0.8,
# )
# plt.show()

# Print the confusion matrix to show that the clusters mimic the target
print(confusion_matrix(df[target], df["cluster"]))
```

Small notes on your original code:

- What's the point in having MDS with the same number of components as before?
- Why did you choose DBScan over other methods?

Comment: Thanks, TSNE seems very useufl! 
Q1: I've edited the question showing the example from the lecture I am following. I was hoping touse MDS with the same number of dimensions, to help separate the classes like in the example image in the edited question. I think it made more sense to use KernelPCA instead. 
Q2: It was an assigment were we had to try a few different alghorithms. K-Means and Agglormerative Clustering worked ok, but was expecitng DBscan to work better, but probably i was wrong as the clusters are not visually separate.